# Unable to connect to samba via hostname from Windows 10

Tags: windows, samba

I have set up SMB shares on my Raspberry Pi and connect to it via it's hostname `\\raspberrypi\shared`
which is working correctly with my Windows 7 machine.

But the Windows 10 machine refuses to connect, telling that the user or password is incorrect.
However if I use the IP address of the raspberry Pi instead of it's hostname there is no problem connecting: `\\192.168.0.112\shared`

But it's cumbersome to `ping -4 raspberrypi` every time, to find out it's IP address.

I remember having the same problem with a Windows 8.1 machine.

Is there something different in smb client of Windows 10 compared to Windows 7?
Can it be changed in the smb config?

SMB1.0/CIFS file sharing support (client) is enabled in Windows 10

Config:

```
[global]
    workgroup = workgroup
    server string = MY-SERVER
    security = user
    map to guest = Bad User
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    guest ok = yes
    allow insecure wide links = yes
    unix extensions = no
    log level = 3

[to_password_protected_folder]
    path = /home/pi
    writeable = yes
    valid users = pi

[shared]
    path = /home/shared
    writeable = yes
    force user = pi
    follow symlinks = yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems I've found an answer myself after months of searching.
If I use `raspberrypi.local` instead of just `raspberrypi` as the host name, the Windows machine has no problems with authentication.

I remember reading something about Windows adding the domain name to the hostname during samba authentication, which is wrong in this case and leads to the described problem. But unfortunately I can't find the source any more.

If someone please could explain that problem better, I would mark his answer as correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the newer versions of Windows don't use WINS to find the IP address.

You should register the IP address with DNS, then all the Windows machines should find Samba on your Raspberry.

Comment: `"You should register the IP address with DNS"` - that sounds like vague advice

Comment: @JaromandaX, at least it is an answer .... the question is not even related to the RPi and should not even be here .... the OP may already know how to do that

Comment: true - sorry you felt the need to defend yourself :p

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how to register the IP address with DNS. @jsotola Sorry, that the question is not related to raspi itself, but I see here many questions about configuring samba or similar Linux related.

Comment: That depends on what you are using for DNS.